# Is there a standard for oil pipeline symbology?

Tags: cartography, symbology

To develop a map for specific public is recommended using some special symbology. I am in charge to develop a map for an audience in oil pipeline business, I would like to produce my map using a standard symbology, but so far I have not found any.

I just read some post here that led me to the INSPIRE documentation, but it does not fulfil my requirements. Does anyone have information about this topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ESRI has a standard for Petroleum related symbology:

http://downloads.esri.com/support/documentation/ao_/Petroleum.pdf

Shell has also just released its 'industry standard' symbology:

http://www.ogp.org.uk/news/2014/shell-releases-its-standard-legend-to-industry-and-academia/

I work with a slightly different symbology for pipelines but I think the general rule is:

- Oil - Green
- Gas - Red
- Water - Blue
- Service - Black

Obviously there are tonnes of variations and pipeline types but there's some info there to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!!, could you lead me with some terminology? i get lost when I read "Gravity Main"
"Force Main/Purge Line/Stub Out"...I'm not so quite educated in the petroleum business...so..I do not undertand these terms.

Comment: Actually I would follow the Shell guidelines now that I look more closely(http://www.ogp.org.uk/files/4713/9081/4569/SR.12.12047_-_Shell_Standard_Legend_RED._Discipline_Quality_Standard.pdf) They have a better standard and the types are explained better.